# Why does the label of a input in Bootstrap dictate the size of an input box?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with some inline inputs but the size of the label seems to dictate the size of the input box.

HTML

```
 <div class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="address3">Town</label>
 <input type="text" name="sublocality" class="form-control fixedWidth" id="address3" placeholder="town">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="address4">City</label>
 <input type="text" name="locality" class="form-control fixedWidth" id="address4" placeholder="City">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Result

[image]

i would like all the input boxes to be the same width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `col-sm-*` in all of your `form-group`, for example:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="address3">Town</label>
    <input type="text" name="sublocality" class="form-control fixedWidth" id="address3" placeholder="town">
</div>
```